# Close the drop down of an Item in a list when clicking on a sibling Item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu

I have a menu with multiple levels. I want to know how do I collapse an active menu item when we clicking on another menu item who are siblings (Items at the same level.) I have implemented the below Jquery code. But it doesn't give the expected output. Even though this is a WordPress plugin this functionality is not available from the plugin. Hence any help would be appreciated.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.elementor-nav-menu ul li a').click(function (e) {
  // remove the active class with every click
  var same = jQuery(this).hasClass('active');
  var siblings = jQuery(this).parent('.menu-item').parent().children();
  siblings.find('a.active + .sub-menu').slideUp();
  siblings.find('a').removeClass('active'); 
  
  if (jQuery(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu') && !same) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown();
  }
});
});
```

```css
.elementor-nav-menu a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.elementor-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.elementor-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.elementor-navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.elementor-navigation ul li,
.elementor-navigation ul ul li {
    text-align: left;
}

.no-js .elementor-navigation ul ul {
    display: block;
}

.elementor-navigation ul .eltoggled-on {
    display: block;
}

.elementor-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
    margin-right: 56px;
}

.eldropdown-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    content: "";
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 48px;
}

.eldropdown-toggle:after {
    border: 0 solid #d1d1d1;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
}

.eldropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

.eldropdown-toggle:focus:after {
    border-color: transparent;
}

.eldropdown-toggle.eltoggled-on:after {
    content: "\f106";
}

.elementor-menu-toggle {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 1.076923077em 0;
    padding: 0.569230769em 0.769230769em;
    clear: both;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.no-js .elementor-menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.elementor-menu-toggle.eltoggled-on:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .elementor-menu-toggle {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-size: 1.0rem;
        margin: 1.3125em 0;
        padding: 0.8125em 0.875em 0.6875em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 56.875em) {
    .elementor-menu {
        display: block;
        -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
        -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
        flex: 0 1 auto;
    }

    .elementor-navigation {
        margin: 0 -0.875em;
    }

    .elementor-navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .elementor-navigation a {
        outline-offset: -8px;
        padding: 1em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul {
        display: block;
        left: -999em;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99999;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul ul {
        top: -1px;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul ul:before,
    .elementor-navigation ul ul ul:after {
        border: 0;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul a {
        white-space: normal;
        width: 12.6875em;
    }

    .elementor-navigation li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-navigation li.focus > ul {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
        left: 100%;
        right: auto;
    }

    .elementor-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 2.25em;
    }

    .elementor-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
        content: "\f107";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.625em;
        top: 1.25em;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul .menu-item-has-children > a {
        padding-right: 2.0625em;
    }

    .elementor-navigation ul ul .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
        right: 0.5625em;
        top: 0.875em;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .elementor-align-left .elementor-navigation ul ul .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .elementor-align-left .elementor-navigation li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-align-left .elementor-navigation li.focus > ul {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }

    .elementor-align-left .elementor-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-align-left .elementor-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
        left: 100%;
        right: auto;
    }


    .elementor-align-right .elementor-navigation ul ul .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .elementor-align-right .elementor-navigation li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-align-right .elementor-navigation li.focus > ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    .elementor-align-right .elementor-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
    .elementor-align-right .elementor-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 100%;
    }

    .eldropdown-toggle,
    .elementor-navigation ul .eldropdown-toggle.eltoggled-on,
    .elementor-menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-1" class="elementor-nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-247">
        <a href="#" class="item">Makeup</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-251">
                    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Complexion</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-261"><a href="#" class="sub-item">Concealer</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-264"><a href="#" class="sub-item">Foundation</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-260"><a href="#" class="sub-item">CC Cream</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-256">
                    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Palettes</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-320"><a href="#" class="sub-item">Complexion Palettes</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-321"><a href="#" class="sub-item">Eyeshadow Palettes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
    
            </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-247">
        <a href="#" class="item">Perfume</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-251">
                    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Mens</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-261"><a href="#" class="sub-item">AXE</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-264"><a href="#" class="sub-item">DARK</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-260"><a href="#" class="sub-item">FOG</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-256">
                    <a href="#" class="sub-item">Ladies</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu nav-menu--dropdown">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-320"><a href="#" class="sub-item">FA</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-321"><a href="#" class="sub-item">Victoria Secret</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
    
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your shown example is just a nested unordered list with clickable links. You need to elaborate how your menu should work. You talk about collappsing submenus, but dont show how they expand all submenus in your example are expanded without even having an "active" class. Did you forget your CSS ?

Comment: @Lapskaus I have added the CS file as well.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Check your snippet by running it yourself. Does this reflect your problem ?